# Django SQLITE database showing wrong column names

Tags: python, django, sqlite, django-models, django-database

```
from django.db import models

class Players(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField()
    role = models.TextField(default="role")
    salary = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2,max_digits=4)
    team = models.TextField()
```

[Actual CSV FILE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XunTd.png)
[SQLITE Table created on Django](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lEhRx.png)

I am importing a csv file into a SQLITE table on Django, which I have attached below. This is the code I have written in the models.py fil to create the table. However, the SQLITE table created (attached below) has the column names in the wrong order.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you incorrectly inserted data in database. Try this after you made migration and created table.

```
import csv, sqlite3

connection = sqlite3.connect("sqlite:///your_filename.db")
cur = connection.cursor()

with open('data.csv','r') as file:
    # csv.DictReader uses first line in file for column headings by default
    raw_data = csv.DictReader(file) # comma is default delimiter
    data = []
    for raw_record in raw_data:
        record = []
        for col_name in raw_data.keys():
            record.append(raw_record[col_name])
        data.append(tuple(record))
query = "INSERT INTO players (name, role, salary, team) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s);"
cur.executemany(query, data)
connection.commit()
connection.close()
```

Comment: In which file should I add this code?

Comment: You can create new python file and just execute it. The file should be on the same level as your database file and csv file, according to the example.